# Can I connect one router to another as a device and share internet connection but. It a lan?

Tags: wireless-networking, router, internet

I don't have any internet for 1 month and need to wfh on a local area network for development. My router provides this. Is there any way to pipe in an internet connection from the cafes router downstairs without opening my network to people in the cafe? I want to connect my router to their router, but as a single device basically.

Comment: I think you need to edit your comment and make it more descriptive. 
Add your router's brand name and model exactly. Add more technical data for people to be able to help you out. If you can connect through the internet from your wireless, you can use your ethernet card to share the internet connection with the rest your LAN through NAT. However, you need to provide more specific technical data

Comment: TP-Link AC1750 Dual Band Wireless Gigabit Cable Router, 2 USB, 2.0 Ports, Support Guest Network, UK Plug (Archer C7). I've just bought this, if it's unsuitable for this I'd love to know!

Comment: Sorry I wrote this while I was out, its a bit brief. If you have any ideas it would be very helpful. Can I use an ethernet card on a Macbook pro for this purpose?

Comment: Yes, you can use your Macbook for this purpose. 
First, connect to the WiFi with your Macbook. Then connect the ethernet port of the Mac to the blue port of your router, and finally, Open System Preferences on your Mac, go into the Sharing menu under Internet & Wireless and choose Internet Sharing from the list on the left.  "share your connection from Wi-Fi to computers on Ethernet".
Then, click the "Internet Sharing" checkbox to enable the service.
All the computers connected to your router, will have an internet connection.